# Limit with ties in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, limit

I have a database with movie data: title and year. I need a query to perform a count of movies by year and return the year with the highest count. My struggle is that I need it to be dynamic, so if there is a tie, it should return all the "tied" years.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
db.movies.aggregate({$group : {_id : "$year", movies: {$sum : 1}}}, {$sort : {"movies" : -1}}, {$limit : 3})
```

Right now I have a tie between three movies, hence the limit 3 but I would like it to be dynamic.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use double `$group`, the second one group by count.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$year",
    movies: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$movies",
    "yearList": {
      "$push": "$$ROOT._id"
    }
  }
},
{
  $sort: {
    "_id": -1
  }
},
{
  "$limit": 1
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K7TUBZqiF8U)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Query

- uses `$setWindowFields`, requires MongoDB >= 5
- sort by movies (it has the movie count)
- `$denseRank` will rank the members but same `movie count` will get the same rank
- we filter max rank 3 (if duplicates it might be more like in the example bellow)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49ed)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$setWindowFields": 
    {"output": {"dense-rank": {"$denseRank": {}}},
     "sortBy": {"movies": -1}}},
  {"$match": {"$expr": {"$lte": ["$dense-rank", 3]}}},
  {"$unset": ["dense-rank"]}])
```